# Unity shader (HLSL) equivalent of Unity macro "COMPUTE_EYEDEPTH"

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, hlsl, urp

Converting a Unity's cgim shader to HLSL (URP). I am stuck on Unity's macro in depth texture "COMPUTE_EYEDEPTH", Docs: https://docs.unity3d.com/2020.1/Documentation/Manual/SL-DepthTextures.html. Can you share HLSL equivalent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You download the built-in unity shaders for each unity version here: https://unity3d.com/get-unity/download/archive by pressing either "Download (Windows)" or "Download (Mac)" and then "Built-in shaders".

Open the zip in IDE like VSCode and search for `COMPUTE_EYEDEPTH` and you will see the macro in the file UnityCG.cginc

```
#define COMPUTE_EYEDEPTH(o) o = -UnityObjectToViewPos( v.vertex ).z
```

Repeat the same for `UnityObjectToViewPos` and you will find this in the same file UnityCG.cginc

```
// Tranforms position from object to camera space
inline float3 UnityObjectToViewPos( in float3 pos )
{
    return mul(UNITY_MATRIX_V, mul(unity_ObjectToWorld, float4(pos, 1.0))).xyz;
}
```

I hope that's starting point to implement it in HLSL for URP.

Comment: Thanks, I'm following it.

[Apologies for vote, need 15 reputations to show it]